# Magento 2: Why the product not show in category page (reindex)?

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, cron, reindex, magento-catalog

I have well mastered Magento 1.x, however, I'm starting on 2.1.7 and what caused me confusion is the index manager, since I created a product and after saving it does not appear on the page of the categories

I have the cron job well created:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php7.0 /path/to/magento2/bin/magento cron:run

*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php7.0 /path/to/magento2/update/cron.php 

*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/php7.0 /path/to/magento2/bin/magento setup:cron:run
```

Now, I know that after creating the product I go to the console and run this command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Everything works, but the management of the store will be done by the end client, person without access to the server and without ssh knowledge and Linux commands.

I find it hard to believe that to publish a product in Magento 2 you have to forcefully run a command line

**NOTE: how to work the "Update on save" mode, because away state in red color.**

Thanks!

Comment: Validate that your cron jobs are running, add >> cron.log or such to each line. You can also find more details in the bin/magento --help

Comment: Is running, in fact I have the logs as you say, I just did not put them here so I did not make the longest lines